# VSCode How to change the border color and border size in Hight Contrast color theme?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am very happy when using vscode and i love the High Contrast color theme but I don't like its border (the blue border that i marked with red in the screenshot below). I have searched in the theme-default folder but i can't change it. Does anyone know how to change it?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3pdA.png)

Answer (score 2):

I work on VSCode. This cannot be changed currently without editing our bundled UI css, which I recommend against.

Support for theming UI elements like this is being tracked by https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3112

If you feel this color should be changed, please [open a new issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues) or submit a PR with the proposed fix. There seem to be multiple places where the boarder color is defined. Look for css files the use `#6FC3DF` for border-color. `.hc-black` is the high contrast selector

Comment: Thanks you but i already capture and search the color #7FC3DF but have no result. I'm trying to search on file hc-black.json on folder theme-default but i can't found it >"<

Comment: These colors are not in the theme, they are part of the css that defines VSCode's UI. Trying cloning the entire [VSCode repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode) and searching in there